# how to have query in flutter based upon the conditions?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to have queries processed for `StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>` based on certain conditions which I am not able to do. Below are the queries coded

```
    Query query;
    if (a==b){
    query = Firestore.instance.collection('collection1');
    }
    
    else if (c==d){
    query = Firestore.instance.collection('collection2');
    }
    else if (e==f){
    query = Firestore.instance.collection('collection3');
    }
```

Inside Widget Build

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(

    stream: query.snapshots(),
    builder: (context,snapshot){
      if (!snapshot.hasData){
        return Text("Loading");
      }

      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){

            String names = snapshot.data.documents[index]['name'];
            List steps = List.castFrom(snapshot.data.documents[index]["steps"])


            return NameCard(names: names,steps: steps);

          });
    },

  )
```

I need to switch the queries after the conditions are checked and then the query which is satifying the conditions of `if-else` shall proceed further to make the things happen `StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>` but if there is only one query it works perfectly fine. but when I tried to switch queries depending upon the conditions it does not work, it gives error of null snapshot.

How should I achieve it to switch the queries based upon the conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this in each condition :

```
setState(){
     query = Firestore.instance.collection('collection1');
   }
```